# Angular routing me muestra por segundos vista incorrecta

Tags: angular

Buen día, no entiendo por qué razón el *routing* me muestra una vista por un momento y después ya me muestra la que le pido. Tengo 4 módulos distintos: el global por defecto, *auth*, *private*, *private/alumnos* y *private/admin*.

Concretamente, el problema está en el *auth* donde tengo el componente *login*. Una vez logueado, ejecuto esta línea de código para ir a un componente concreto dentro del módulo *private/alumnos*:

```
this.router.navigate(['private/alumnos/inicio']);
```

Sin embargo, por un momento me muestra otro componente y automáticamente después me manda al componente correcto.
En el módulo de alumnos, por ejemplo, que es el que contiene ese componente este es el código del routing ya revisé y no llamo al componente que se aparece por un momento en otro lado.

¿Qué podrá ser?

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: LayoutComponent,
    children: [
      {
      path: '',
      component: InicioComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'inicio',
        component: InicioComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'pagos',
        component: RegistroPagosComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'tareas',
        component: TareasComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'listado-pagos',
        component: ListadoPagosComponent,
      }
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AlumnosRoutingModule { }
```

No creo que tenga nada que ver con el problema pero en el *routing* de *private* tengo esto:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'alumnos',
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    loadChildren: () => import('./alumnos/alumnos.module').then(m => m.AlumnosModule),
  },
  {
    path: 'admin',
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    loadChildren: () => import('./admin/admin.module').then(m => m.AdminModule),
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class PrivateRoutingModule { }
```

Comment: Puedes subir un ejemplo a stackblitz?

Answer (score 0):

Eso puede darse si InicioComponent no es un hijo o está relacionado directamente con LayoutComponent y/o hay otra ruta en la misma url que tengas con LayoutComponent.  Prueba cambiar por un momento la ruta de InicioComponente y verificar que se corrija el problema. Si es así puedes o cambiar la lógica entre los dos componentes o manejar dos rutas aparte.

También puede ser que la lógica que tienes implementada redirija primero al otro componente que mencionas en la pregunta, en cuyo caso tendrías que revisar y corregir la redirección.

Answer (score 0):

Tus rutas están duplicadas.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: LayoutComponent,
    children: [
      {
      path: '',
      component: InicioComponent,
      },
```

Se puede observar que la ruta raíz "/" para este módulo está duplicado y por lo tanto responde a 2.

Cuando entras a "/alumnos" tu path raíz se convierte en todo lo posterior a, es decir: "/alumnos/[tu_root_es_este]" (donde obvio la palabra "tu_root_es_este" no existe, espero explicarme).

Por lo que consideramos esta parte.

Cuando quieras hacer un children de una ruta, asegúrate que esa children corresponde a una sección, es decir:

```
/alumnos/ <--Tu raíz
/alumnos/listado <--Tu primer children
/alumnos/listado/1 <--Tu segundo children con un parámetro
/alumnos/calificaciones <--Tu tercer children
```

Y así sucesivamente.

En este caso lo mejor que puedes hacer es ponerle a tu path "raíz" que mejor te redirija a "/inicio" para que termines en "/alumnos/inicio" y convierte este path "inicio" como parte de tus rutas raíz, no como rutas hijas.